# Increase Column Size for SQL Server SQLCMD

Tags: sql-server, linux, sqlcmd

Connecting to SQL Server through [SQLCMD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017) which allows me to run SQL queries from my linux machine.  Here is my working command:

```
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S thedb.server.database.windows.net -d db_123 -U user_123 -P pass_123 -y 50 -Y 50 -I -Q "$SQL_QUERY" -s"|"
```

However, the problem is that I have columns in which is up to 1000 characters long.  So when I increase the size of the columns per the documentation, I get no result:

```
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S thedb.server.database.windows.net -d db_123 -U user_123 -P pass_123 -y 1000 -Y 1000 -I -Q "$SQL_QUERY" -s"|"
```

Any ideas on how to increase the size so I receive my data?  thank you

Comment: Why are you trying to display the data in the CLI? If you have columns that wide, you should export it directly to file.

Comment: I'm actually saving that into a variable, then processing it there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server's sqlcmd is truncating my columns returned, and increasing the size causes no result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57015860/sql-servers-sqlcmd-is-truncating-my-columns-returned-and-increasing-the-size-c)